# Add and Remove Data from one table to another - Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables in my View, I would like a way to Add and Remove Data in the table from one to the other. Currently this is my Partial View and the Add Table:

```
<div id="table-scroller">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable catalogueContractsTable admin-form theme-primary" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
    <thead id="tableHeader">
        <tr>
            <th class="bg-white">Name</th>
            <th class="bg-white">Contract Type</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Start Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">End Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Termination Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scrollable">
        @foreach (var contract in Model.Contracts)
        {
            var rightNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var classValue = "";
            if (contract.Selected)
            {
                classValue = "selected";
                if (contract.TerminationDate != default(DateTime?))
                {
                    classValue += contract.TerminationDate < rightNow ? "bg-danger extra-light" : "bg-warning extra-light";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (contract.TerminationDate != default(DateTime?))
                {
                    classValue = contract.TerminationDate < rightNow ? "bg-danger extra-light" : "bg-warning extra-light";
                }
            }
            <tr class='@classValue'>
                <td>
                    @contract.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @contract.ContractTypeDescription
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    @contract.From.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    @if (contract.To != default(DateTime?))
                    {
                        @contract.To.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                    }
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                        @if (contract.TerminationDate != default(DateTime?))
                        {
                            @contract.TerminationDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                        }
                </td>
                <td class="updateTableRow text-center">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn" id="AddContractBtn" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like it so that when you click on the Add button it is then passed to this table:

```
<div id="include-table-scroller">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable catalogueContractsTable admin-form theme-primary" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
    <thead id="tableHeader">
        <tr>
            <th class="bg-white">Name</th>
            <th class="bg-white">Contract Type</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Start Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">End Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Termination Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs bg-white text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scrollable">
        @foreach (var contract in Model.Contracts)
        {
            var rightNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var classValue = "";
            if (contract.Selected)
            {
                classValue = "selected";
                if (contract.TerminationDate != default(DateTime?))
                {
                    classValue += contract.TerminationDate < rightNow ? "bg-danger extra-light" : "bg-warning extra-light";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (contract.TerminationDate != default(DateTime?))
                {
                    classValue = contract.TerminationDate < rightNow ? "bg-danger extra-light" : "bg-warning extra-light";
                }
            }
            <tr class='@classValue'>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs"></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs"></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs"></td>
                <td class="updateTableRow text-center">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn" id="AddContractBtn" value="Remove" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Then if I select Remove it then passes pack to the Add table. I am not sure what would be the best approach to use, whether its better using something like JQuery or if you can do it using C#.

Comment: It should be done with javascript/jquery (c# code runs on the server so you would need to post back to the server). And as a side note, duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html - use a class name in your buttons instead

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I will change the `id` attributes now. Do you know how I would achieve it using JQuery?  As I did think about putting in a GET/POST Request, but really its just showing it adding and removing in the dom. As I have a GET/POST that will get the data from both tables and then post it to the server when its created.

Comment: Give each `<tbody>` a `id` attribute and then in the buttons `.click()` handler - `$('#otherTable').append($(this).closest('tr');`

Comment: But not sure what you mean by making a POST - you do not have a `<form>` or any form controls (and you would not want to post back all the data anyway)

Comment: Ive just looked at the main view, there is no GET/POST in there currently. But your right it would be a lot of data.

Comment: If you are wanting to update the database based on which table its in, then you would make an ajax call in the buttons `.click()` handler to a method that updates the data (just passing the `id` of the record - and return a `JsonResult` indicating success or failure, and if successful, then move the row (although its not clear what you want to do)

Comment: Basically, I just want a way that when you click Add it moves it into the Include table. Then if you click Remove it then puts it back in the Add table. JQuery should be fine for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173971/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html, so start by removing them from your buttons (use a class name instead)

You can move the `<tr>` associated with the button to the other table by handling the `.click()` event and then using

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the tr element
otherTable.append(row); // move it to the other table
```

Give each `<tbody>` an `id` attribute, and give the buttons a class name (say) `class="move"`. Because the rows will be dynamically moved between tables, you will need to use event delegation (`.on` function) for handling the `.click()` event

```
<table>
    <thead> ... </thead>
    <tbody id="include">
        <tr>
            ....
            <td><input type="button" class="move ..." value="Move" /></td>
        </tr>
        .... // more <tr> elements
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <thead> ... </thead>
    <tbody id="exclude">
        ....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then add the following script

```
var include = $('#include');
var exclude = $('#exclude');
include.on('click', '.move', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    exclude.append(row);
});
table2.on('click', '.move', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    include.append(row);
});
```

Note if you want different display text for the buttons in each table, you can change it in  the `.click` handler using `$(this).text('Remove');` (to set the text to "Remove")

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5creL29g/2/) for a working example.